# Unable to type apostrophe in the terminal

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm unable to type the character `'` in urxvt. Nothing happens if I press the button to type it.

If I copy something to the clipboard that contains `'`, and paste it with shift+insert, the text is inserted without the apostrophes.

If I run another application inside the terminal such as `cat` or `vim`, it is usually possible to type `'` into that application. However there are some applications in which I still can't type `'` when I run them, these include `sh`, `bash`, and the terminal emulator found inside neovim. Note that `zsh` does support writing apostrophes.

I also experience this problem inside other emulators than urxvt, such as bash running in emacs, terminator or a simple tty outside the window manager.

Pressing `'` twice doesn't do anything either. The keyboard layout is `us` model `pc105` with options `bksp:bksp_escape,compose:rctrl,caps:backspace`. The window manager is i3, and the distro is arch.

Comment: I haven't tagged the question urxvt since the problem also happens in other emulators, as mentioned in the end of the question.

Comment: urxvt is a terminal emulator, bash is a shell, emacs is a text editor (officially :) . if you try gnome-terminal or konsole or other terminal emulator, does it work? does it work in console? what DE/WM are you using?

Comment: Does it work if you hit `'` twice? What keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: I have added additional information to the question.

Comment: Does it happen in other shells? On many systems, `sh` is also `bash` (just run in POSIX mode). What OS are you using? Do you have any other shells installed to test on? If not, try installing `zsh` or `dash`, both of which should be available in your system's repositories.

Comment: It does appear to work in `zsh`.

Comment: OK, please also tell us i) your OS and whether `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`; ii) the output of `shopt`; iii) the contents of your `~/.inputrc` file; iv) whether this also occurs if you log in as another user. I don't really know if `shopt` or `inputrc` will tell us anything useful. I can't think of any setting that will reproduce what you describe, but we may as well check.

Comment: i) `realpath /bin/sh` outputs `/usr/bin/bash`.

Comment: ii) `shopt` outputs [this](http://pastebin.com/tHpQWp4k).

Comment: iii) `~/.inputrc` contains [this](http://pastebin.com/m9GKt6ir).

Comment: iv) I can type `'` as root.

Comment: Output of `stty -a` ? Does it work if you press `Ctrl+V` then `'` ? Do you have this problem if you run `urxvt -e bash --norc` ?